# CURL request behaving inconsistently.

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm making a simple curl GET request from my server (Debian/Apache/PHP) to another 3rd party server. However the request takes about a minute. However, if I

- Execute the same request as a curl line from my terminal, I
  get instant results
- Execute the same PHP script on an online PHP playground, I get instant
  results.( This was a like a sanity check for my code. Looks like there is no code error.)

From my server, if I make a simple request to http://www.google.com, I get instant results as well.

What could the possible issue be?

Comment: Have you tried running `curl` from the production server where `apache` is and if so what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at a packet capture or strace output. A common cause of delays might be DNS problems, especially ipv6 DNS timing out.

Comment: @KannanMohan I don't have access to the production server where apache has been installed.

Comment: @covener - you were spot on. It was a DNS issue. Unfortunately I saw your post after I figured this out. Thanks!